# Can you update the files being compared in vscode like in PyCharm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compare

When comparing files, PyCharm let you update either from the other by mouse clicks.
Can VSCode "compare" do the same thing?

Comment: are you talking about VS Code's SCM merge feature? Its SCM diff feature? Its "Compare files" feature?

Comment: I am referring to `ctrl+p` - `compare files` feature. In the opened up window, two files are side by side, showing their diff. However, I can't update either easily within this interface.

Comment: what do you mean by "can't easily update"? You can edit within them, no? Can you please elaborate on what's making it difficult?

Comment: I mean in pycharm, you can update an edited line e.g. the left from the right by one-click. In Vscode, although it clearly shows what the differences are, I can't update either side from the other by a click - I have to manually type to update.

Comment: please show before and after screenshots of what you mean. It's not clear to me from the description you just gave